# Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to use a stored procedure in c#. I create the stored procedure in sql server and I call it in the program. But when I use the breakpoint feature, I come to know that the data is not retrieved from the db as the breakpoint skips over the loop..

.aspx code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="store" />
<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

c# code:

```
public void store(object sender, EventArgs ser)
{
    try
    {
        // c reate and open a connection object
        SqlConnection conn = Class3.GetConnection();

        // 1. create a command object identifying the stored procedure
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storeprocedure3", conn);

        // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // 3. add parameter to command, which will be execute the command
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // iterate through results, printing each to console
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Label9.Text = rdr["menuename"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception sa)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sa);
    }
}
```

stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure3     
AS
BEGIN
    select menuename from menue;

END
GO
```

Comment: Does your stored procedure return data if you directly run it against the database eg in Sql Management Studio?

Comment: I notice that you asign a scalar value to the property:
Label9.Text= rdr["menuename"].ToString();
You should consider using cmd.ExecuteScalar() instead of cmd.ExecuteReader() in case you are retrieving single value from the stored procedure

Comment: - is there an exception happening? (hint: `Console.WriteLine` is not very useful in a web application)
- is the connection executing as the right user? (`from menue` is ambiguous - it depends on the user) - when is this running? also; needs a lot more `using`...

Comment: Have you tried running your procedure directly against the database (using Sql Server Management Studio) to see it it really returns any rows? Also, using Console.WriteLine in an ASP.Net-project is kinda useless, make sure to put a breakpoint in your catch-clause as well to see if any exceptions occur and then find a better way to handle your exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

You have a mismatch in your program ( **procedure3** vs **storeprocedure3**)

use this code

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procedure3 ", conn);
```

and close your connection

```
 SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

Comment: ...if this is a C# stored procedure, the connection would come from the context, and you wouldn't have (want) to close it or dispose it

Answer (score 5):

IMO, here's the biggest and most likely problem:

```
catch (Exception sa)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sa);
}
```

I *imagine* it is trying **really** hard to tell you what is wrong, but you silenced it. There is **no reason whatsoever** to `try`/`catch` this; if that doesn't work, *something is very wrong* - let it error. Read the exception details.

If I were being picky (and, frankly, I am) - you **need** a lot more `using` here, i.e.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = Class3.GetConnection())
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("whatever", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
           // do something
        }
    }
}
```

or, frankly easier, use a tool like dapper:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = Class3.GetConnection())
{
    foreach(var obj in conn.Query("whatever",
          commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
    {
        string menuename = obj.menuename;
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does `EXEC procedure` produce any results?

Also in your code you have referenced the stored procedure as `storeprocedure3` when in fact the procedure name appears to be `procedure3`

Change the line to:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procedure3", conn);
```